# How do I echo out a name -only if- specific rows in one table match specific rows in another based on an id?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

Here's my problem: I'm making a crafting system for a game, and I already have my database filled with information for resources required to craft items.

Here are what my relevant tables look like:

> ```
> table #edible_resources
> (edible_resource_id, edible_resource_name, hunger_points, degeneration_id)
>
> table #edible_ground
> (id, resource, amount, location)
>
> table #req_crafting_edible
> (req_crafting_edible_id, edible_resource_id, req_resource_amount, created_item_id)
>
> table #items
> (item_id, item_name, degeneration_id, is_grounded, is_stackable, can_equip, can_edit)
> ```

What I want to do is -only- echo out the craftable item's name if, and only if -all- required resources (and their required amounts) are on the ground in the location of the character.

I have a query that comes close:

```
SELECT items.item_name, items.item_id FROM items
INNER JOIN req_crafting_edible
ON req_crafting_edible.created_item_id = items.item_id
INNER JOIN edible_ground
ON edible_ground.resource = req_crafting_edible.edible_resource_id
AND edible_ground.amount >= req_crafting_edible.req_resource_amount
WHERE edible_ground.location = $current_location
GROUP BY items.item_name
ORDER BY items.item_name
```

But this shows me craftable items regardless if I have ALL the required items in the area. It shows me items as long as I have -one- of their required resources.

Is there a way to only show the name of a craftable item only if I have -all- the required resources (and their amounts) in edible_ground where location = $current_location?

For more information on what I've tried:

```
$get_char = mysql_query("SELECT current_char FROM accounts WHERE account_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$current_char = mysql_result($get_char, 0, 'current_char');

$get_loc = mysql_query("SELECT current_location FROM characters WHERE character_id = $current_char");
$current_location = mysql_result($get_loc, 0, 'current_location');

//---------------------------------------------------------------COOKED FOOD
$get_food = mysql_query("SELECT items.item_name, items.item_id FROM items
INNER JOIN req_crafting_edible
ON req_crafting_edible.created_item_id = items.item_id
INNER JOIN edible_ground
ON edible_ground.resource = req_crafting_edible.edible_resource_id
AND edible_ground.amount >= req_crafting_edible.req_resource_amount
WHERE edible_ground.location = $current_location
GROUP BY items.item_name
ORDER BY items.item_name");
while ($food = mysql_fetch_array($get_food)){
  echo $food['item_name'].'<br>';
}
```

This returns:

- Baked Fish
- Charred Fish
- Fish Soup
- Glazed Berry
- Cake
- Grilled Fish
- Sashimi
- Seafood Soup
- Sushi
- Udon

On the ground:

- 1 fish
- 1 honey

Even though fish soup, berry cake, udon etc needs much more than just the one fish that's in the area.

Can anyone help me figure this out? I'd be forever grateful; I've spent a few days already trying to myself. Please?

And before anyone says anything, I know I need to start using mysqli; unfortunately I didn't even realize it existed when I started to make the game (and learn PHP at the same time months ago), so I'll have to painfully go back and change it all in an update.

Comment: try moving this line `AND edible_ground.amount >= req_crafting_edible.req_resource_amount ` to the end of your existing `WHERE` clause.  edit: actually that won't get you there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `HAVING` clause to check the count of the records you are grouping through the `INNER JOIN`s.

```
HAVING count(*) = (
  SELECT count(*)
    FROM req_crafting_edible
    WHERE req_crafting_edible.created_item_id = items.item_id
)
```

**Edit:**

So basically you need to know two pieces of information:

- How many different resources are required
- Do each of those resources have the required amounts

The first is solved by the sub query above.

Your query as-is satisfies the second point but only for 1 resource.

`HAVING` basically does some special magic on your group clause. `HAVING count(*)` means there are X records being grouped together. Because of how the join works, you will have 1 item.name for each resource. The sub select gives you the count of how many different resources, and therefore grouped records, are needed for that item. Comparing that sub query with the count(*) of the grouping ensures you have all the needed resources.

And here is the final query, modifying your code above:

```
SELECT items.item_name, items.item_id
  FROM items
    INNER JOIN req_crafting_edible
      ON req_crafting_edible.created_item_id = items.item_id
    INNER JOIN edible_ground
      ON edible_ground.resource = req_crafting_edible.edible_resource_id
        AND edible_ground.amount >= req_crafting_edible.req_resource_amount
  WHERE edible_ground.location = $current_location
  GROUP BY items.item_name
  HAVING count(*) = (
    SELECT count(*)
      FROM req_crafting_edible
      WHERE req_crafting_edible.created_item_id = items.item_id
  )
  ORDER BY items.item_name
```

Comment: I've never seen this before, so I'm not sure how to use this, even reading about it in the mysql manual. Why would I need the count of records that I'm grouping? Am I comparing it to something else? I'm sorry, I'm just confused because you gave me a query but no other information, so I'm not sure what to do with it. Can you please elaborate, so I can at least know how to test it or build off of it?

Comment: I edited the above to give you more information. Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You only actually want the data from the items table, right?  If so I would move to using an exists model:

```
SELECT I.item_name, I.item_id FROM items I
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT created_item_id
   FROM req_crafting_edible R
   WHERE R.created_item_id = I.item_id
     AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT G.resource
        FROM edible_ground G
        WHERE G.resource = R.edible_resource_id
          AND edible_ground.location = $current_location
          AND G.amount >= R.req_resource_amount))
ORDER BY I.item_name
```

I don't have your database to check this, but the logic goes like this:

1. Find the items that don't have any unsatisfied requirements.
2. Find the unsatisfied requirements for the current item. (IE. Find
   requirements that don't have resources on the ground)
3. Find the edible resources that match the current requirement, are at
   this location, and have enough.

I don't work in mysql as much at the moment, but let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: The edible_ground.location in the third WHERE clause should be G.location for anyone else trying this out with their own database environment.
This gives me a gigantic list of many items in the items table regardless of resources relevance. EX: Baked Fish, Bone Armor, Bone Club, Bone Dagger, Bone Fire, Bone Fishing Pole, etc. Since there aren't any bones in the edible_ground table, that's not what I'm looking for. Though curiously I've never had to use WHERE EXISTS, or NOT before, so I couldn't actually tell you part of the query I need/don't need. Thank you for the effort and reply though.